# Illegal String Offset, Print_R Shows correct value?

Tags: php, database, warnings

I am getting these errors:

`Warning: Illegal string offset 'approved' in C:... on line 137`

`Warning: Illegal string offset 'approved' in C:... on line 147`

However, I check with print_r() what values I can call and get this:

```
Array (
    [0] => 3
    [id] => 3
    [1] => 3
    [user_fk] => 3
    [2] => > Jailbot 2.0
    [title] => > Jailbot 2.0
    [3] => 1
    [approved] => 1
)
```

So why isn't it letting me call approved?

PHP:

```
$avatarQuery = "SELECT * FROM avatars WHERE user_fk = {$id} LIMIT 1";
$avatarSet = mysql_query($avatarQuery, $connection);
confirm_query($avatarSet);
$count = mysql_num_rows($avatarSet);
if($count == 1){
    $avatar = mysql_fetch_array($avatarSet);
    $avatar = $avatar['picture'];
    $avatarApproved = $avatar['approved'];
}else{
    $avatar = "images/noImage.png";
}
$titleQuery = "SELECT * FROM titles WHERE user_fk = {$id} LIMIT 1";
$titleSet = mysql_query($titleQuery, $connection);
confirm_query($titleSet);
$title = mysql_fetch_array($titleSet);
$title = $title['title'];
$titleApproved = $title['approved'];
```

Comment: `$title = $title['title']; $titleApproved = $title['approved'];`  This might be why.  Notice the name of the variable you assigned the `title` to.

Answer (score 2):

```
$avatar = $avatar['picture'];
$avatarApproved = $avatar['approved'];
```

The first line overrwrites $avatar with the value of $avatar['picture'], so $avatar is no longer an array when you execute the second line; and you're doing the same with $title in the subsequent query result

Comment: ... I feel stupid. Haha I totally overlooked that! Thanks mark